# Reading a Docx/Doc File in Java

Tags: java

I tried to read a Docx File in java.

But I am getting the error as "The constructor XWPFDocument(FileInputStream) is undefined" in LINE NO: 16 and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from XWPFParagraph[] to List" in LINE NO: 18.

Below are my code.

Used Jars:
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

Can any one please tell me that why Iam getting this and please tell me that how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

```
package com.readindDocx;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

public class ReadingDocument {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("D:/SampleWordFile.docx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();


        for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(para.getText());
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: The error says there is no constructor in class `XWPFDocument ` with parameter `FileInputStream`. Use other contractors of that class.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine on my machine (with a different file of course, but that's not the problem). What version of Apache POI are you using?